# Socket.IO only emits to one client but not the other

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I've made a simple multiplayer word game with a server and two clients, where letter tiles get flipped over in the middle and revealed to both players.

I'm having a problem where the server only emits the "Flip" action to one client but not the other, even though I'm using the socket.emit function, which is supposed to emit to everyone. I've been banging my head against this problem for days right now, and I could really use any advice.

The steps in the "Flip" action are the following.

1. One client emits a "flip request" to the server. The server on receiving "flip request" does 2 things: (1) starts a countdown until the next flip and (2) emits "flip request" to all clients so that they know that the countdown has started.
2. After the server's countdown is finished, the server emits "flip" to all clients, and then all the clients see a letter tile get flipped.

Right now, the problem is:

1. The server only seems to be emitting to one of the clients. This manifests as only one client getting to see the flipped tiles.
2. The sole client that receives the server's messages is always the **second client to connect to the game**. That is, when the server boots up, if Client 1 connects first and then Client 2 connects second, no matter who submits the flip request (Client 1 or Client 2), only Client 2 will see any tiles. I found that very strange.

Here is a simplified version of my code (minus a lot of the game mechanics, just isolating this flip action). Also an image of the game state and the console log is below the code.

client.js

```
// Emits "Flip Request" to the server when you press Enter
function keyhandler(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    // enter key
    if (keyCode == 13){
         console.log('Requesting flip');
         socket.emit('flip_request', 0);
        }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){keyhandler(e)}, false)

var socket = io();

socket.on('flip_request', function (){
    console.log('Received flip request');

    game.flip_status = 'Ready...';
});

socket.on('flip', function (current){
    console.log('Flipped');

    game.current = current;
    game.flip_status = 'Flipped!';
});
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});


io.on('connect', function(socket){
    
    var client_ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-real-ip'];
    
    console.log('Connected to ' + client_ip + '. ID: ' + socket.id)

    check_flip_take = function(){
        if (flip_waiting){
            if (new Date().getTime() > flip_time){
                console.log("Flip!")
                game.flip();
                flip_waiting = false;
                socket.emit('flip', game.current)
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for pending flips and takes
    setInterval(check_flip_take, 100);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`Player ${player_id} disconnected!`)
    });

    socket.on('flip_request', function(){
        console.log("Received flip request")
        flip_waiting = true;
        flip_time = new Date().getTime() + flip_delay; 
        socket.emit('flip_request');
    })
})
```

And here in case it's useful is what the game state looks like. As you can see, in Client 1's (left client's) console log, it says repeatedly "Requesting flip" and that's when the client is submitting a flip request to the server. But only the client on the right (Client 2) gets the "Flipped" event from the server.

[image: What the game looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small issue in your code:

you need to emit with `io` and not with `socket`

that is:

`io.emit('flip_request')`

and

`io.emit('flip', game.current)`

Answer (score 0):

socket.emit only sends it to the socket that trigerred the event, you should use io.emit or you can join sockets in a room with socket.join and